# React Native Firebase Push Notification not getting received in Release Build

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

Please guide me to get it resolved please.
I have installed below npm packages to integrate firebase push notification.
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.5",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.0",

I receive notification in debug mode but if i release the build notification is not working at all.
Here is payload i am using -
{
"notification": {
"title": "notification title",
"body": "notification is ready.",
"click_action": null,
"icon": null
},
"data": {
"xyz":"test",
"click_action": null
},
"to":"xxxxxx",
"content_available": true
}

Comment: Can you add more informations about your problem, android or Ios? if android do you build with a different upload key than debug.keystore? if ios have you a developer account ? 
If you have this problem when you build the android app release with a .keystore different than the one you use to debug then you should add the sha-1 generated from your .release keystore to firebase console

Comment: this is happening in iOS